# embed two .net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a .net based windows application say App-1. Now third party vendor will be providing me another .net based windows application say App-2. Both App-1 & App-2 have UI.

Now I have to embed my App-1 inside App-2. We are different vendors so we don’t want to expose too much code to each other.

What will be the best approach to embed both the application.

Comment: How about exposing your app as a user control inside a dll which app 2 can host ?

Comment: Auburg's solution would be the thing to do. Multiple, discrete applications don't "embed" well.

Comment: Furthermore, you can facilitate this by setting the output type from 'Windows Application' to 'Class Library' in the Application tab in your project settings.

Comment: auburg, can you plz explain how to do that...any link will be great...